How to implement design-time adorner for WPF user component?
I want to provide design-time support for my user control in WPF. I found out about adorners, but unfortunately, I could not implement them (In design time). I used this walkthrough, but it is old and no longer being updated. I would appreciate any help with the topic.
UPDATE:
Based on the answer, that I received on another platform, I am confident that it is not working because of Microsoft.Windows.Design library. In the walkthrough, you have to add a reference to that library, but it is no longer available. I replaced that library with System.Activities.Presentation.Metadata, but it is not working.
Metadata.cs:
using Microsoft.Windows.Design.Features;
using System.Activities.Presentation.Metadata;
namespace CustomControlLibrary.VisualStudio.Design
{
    // Container for any general design-time metadata to initialize. 
    // Designers look for a type in the design-time assembly that  
    // implements IRegisterMetadata. If found, designers instantiate  
    // this class and call its Register() method automatically. 
    internal class Metadata : IRegisterMetadata
    {
        // Called by the designer to register any design-time metadata. 
        public void Register()
        {
            AttributeTableBuilder builder = new AttributeTableBuilder();
            // Add the adorner provider to the design-time metadata.
            builder.AddCustomAttributes(typeof(ButtonWithDesignTime), new  FeatureAttribute(typeof(OpacitySliderAdornerProvider)));
            MetadataStore.AddAttributeTable(builder.CreateTable());
        }
    }
}

OpacitySliderAdornerProvider.cs:
When I tried to copy-paste code from the walkthrough I noticed that PrimarySelectionAdornerProvider encountered some changes, so I had to change the code.
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;
using Microsoft.Windows.Design.Interaction;
using Microsoft.Windows.Design.Model;

namespace CustomControlLibrary.VisualStudio.Design
{
    class OpacitySliderAdornerProvider : PrimarySelectionAdornerProvider
    {
        private ModelItem adornedControlModel;
        private ModelEditingScope batchedChange;
        private Slider opacitySlider;
        private AdornerPanel opacitySliderAdornerPanel;

        public OpacitySliderAdornerProvider()
        {
            opacitySlider = new Slider();
        }
        
        // Activate method now takes only 1 argument
        protected override void Activate(ModelItem item)
        {
            adornedControlModel = item;
            adornedControlModel.PropertyChanged +=
                new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler(
                    AdornedControlModel_PropertyChanged);

            opacitySlider.Minimum = 0;

            AdornerPanel myPanel = this.Panel;

            AdornerPanel.SetHorizontalStretch(opacitySlider, AdornerStretch.Stretch);
            AdornerPanel.SetVerticalStretch(opacitySlider, AdornerStretch.None);

            AdornerPlacementCollection placement = new AdornerPlacementCollection();

            placement.SizeRelativeToContentWidth(1.0, 0);

            placement.SizeRelativeToAdornerDesiredHeight(1.0, 0);

            placement.PositionRelativeToAdornerHeight(-1.0, 0);

            placement.PositionRelativeToAdornerHeight(0, -5);

            AdornerPanel.SetPlacements(opacitySlider, placement);

            opacitySlider.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(slider_Loaded);

            opacitySlider.ValueChanged +=
                new RoutedPropertyChangedEventHandler<double>(
                    slider_ValueChanged);

            opacitySlider.PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp +=
                new System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventHandler(
                    slider_MouseLeftButtonUp);

            opacitySlider.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown +=
                new System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventHandler(
                    slider_MouseLeftButtonDown);

            // This line has been changed
            base.Activate(item);
        }

        public AdornerPanel Panel
        {
            get
            {
                if (this.opacitySliderAdornerPanel == null)
                {
                    opacitySliderAdornerPanel = new AdornerPanel();

                    opacitySliderAdornerPanel.Children.Add(opacitySlider);

                    Adorners.Add(opacitySliderAdornerPanel);
                }

                return this.opacitySliderAdornerPanel;
            }
        }


        
        protected override void Deactivate()
        {
            adornedControlModel.PropertyChanged -=
                new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler(
                    AdornedControlModel_PropertyChanged);
            base.Deactivate();
        }

        void AdornedControlModel_PropertyChanged(
            object sender,
            System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.PropertyName == "Background")
            {
                opacitySlider.Value = GetCurrentOpacity();
            }
        }

        void slider_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            opacitySlider.Value = GetCurrentOpacity();
        }

        void slider_MouseLeftButtonDown(
            object sender,
            System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            batchedChange = adornedControlModel.BeginEdit();
        }

        void slider_MouseLeftButtonUp(
            object sender,
            System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (batchedChange != null)
            {
                batchedChange.Complete();
                batchedChange.Dispose();
                batchedChange = null;
            }
        }

        void slider_ValueChanged(
            object sender,
            RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
        {
            double newOpacityValue = e.NewValue;

            if (newOpacityValue == GetCurrentOpacity())
            {
                return;
            }
            
            // This line has been changed
            ModelProperty backgroundProperty =
                adornedControlModel.Properties["Background"];
            if (!backgroundProperty.IsSet)
            {
                backgroundProperty.SetValue(backgroundProperty.ComputedValue);
            }

            // This line has been changed
            backgroundProperty.Value.Properties["Opacity"].SetValue(newOpacityValue);
        }

        private double GetCurrentOpacity()
        {
            // This line has been changed
            Brush backgroundBrushComputedValue =
                (Brush)adornedControlModel.Properties["Background"].ComputedValue;

            return backgroundBrushComputedValue.Opacity;
        }
    }
}

